# probability of exactly one event occurring vs at least one event occurs

Tags: probability

Set up for the question: hand of 5 cards is dealt - randomly, 1 at a time, w out replacement - from each of **Two standard decks of 52**.

a. the probability that the two hands have **exactly one** card in common?
b. the probability that the two hands have **at least one** card in common?

a. I've begun to calculate a:
total number of hands is $\binom {52}{5}$, the total number of hands excluding the one card in interest is $\binom {47}{4}$. So, the probability of getting exactly one should be $5\binom {47}{4}/\binom {52}{5}$ (because there are 5 cards in a hand). because there is no order and no replacement the formula used is $\binom {n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(1-r)!r!}$.

since there are two decks involved, should I be multiplying the answer by 2?

b. I want to determine how many hands contain no common cards (this is where I am confused) then minus this from 1 to get the total number of hands with at least one common card.

would the total number not containing a common card be $\binom {47}{5}$?

do I then multiply this number by 2 because there are two decks involved?

Hopefully this is is clear..

Comment: The same question was [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858222/a-hand-of-five-cards-is-dealt-randomly-one-card-at-a-time-without-replacement) not long ago. Your approach to the second problem is right. No multiplying by $2$ in either problem.

Comment: Thank you Andre I had not realized. I am still struggling with part b however...

Comment: The argument is as I wrote up the first part. Without loss of generality we may suppose the first hand is specified. The probability of **no** overlap is $\frac{\binom{47}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.